# R data frame column to list (matrix row names)

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe

I need to update my matrix row names according to the values coming from a data frame column. I know that I can update my matrix row names like that:

```
dimnames(A) = list( 
  +   c("row1", "row2"),         # row names 
  +   c("col1", "col2", "col3")) # column names
```

However, the names "row1" , "row2"... should come from the values of a data frame column that have these values:

```
products[,2]
 [1] "Samsung UN48H6350 48\""                                                       "Sharp LC-60LE650U 60"                                                        
 [3] "Roku Streaming Stick with remote"                                             "Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4 16GB, Wi-Fi, 8.4in - White"                       
 [5] "GoPro Here 3 silver"                                                          "Brunswick T Zone 16 lb. bowling ball"                                        
 [7] "SDBS-150 weight set"                                                          "Aventus by Creed Eau De Parfum Spray 4 oz Men"                               
 [9] "Sunny SF-E906"                                                                "Sabrent 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub with Individual Power Switches and LEDs (HB-UMLS)"
[11] "Magnasonic MAG-MM176K"                                                        "NETGEAR Nighthawk AC1900  (R7000)"                                           
[13] "FIDO U2F Security Key"                                                        "Foscam FI9821W V2 white"                                                     
[15] "Samsung UN22F5000"                                                            "D&K Seamless Full Length Leggings"                                           
[17] "Taste of the Wild Dry Dog Food, Hi Prairie Canine Formula with Roasted Bison" "Tidy Cats 4 Count Breeze Litter Pad Refill (Pack of 10)"                     
[19] "PetSafe 6-Volt Lithium Battery (2 Batteries per Pack)"                        "Hakko CHP-170 Micro Clean Cutter"                                            
[21] "Farm Innovators CC-2 Cord Connect Water-Tight Cord Lock - Green"              "Komelon SL2925 Self Lock Speed Mark"                                         
[23] "SanDisk 32GB Ultra Class 10 Micro SDHC"                                       "Samsung (MB-MP32DA/AM)"                                                      
[25] "Panasonic ER-GN30-K"                                                          "Ubervita W700"                                                               
[27] "Baby Einstein Take Along Tunes"                                               "Nosefrida The Snotsucker Nasal Aspirator"                                    
[29] "Baby Einstein Bendy Ball"                                                     "Mommy's Helper Outlet Plugs 36 Pack"                                         
[31] "Marcy Recumbent Exercise Bike: ME-709"                                        "Doc McStuffins Get Better Talking Mobile Cart"                               
[33] "Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare Day Zero Edition (PS3)"                        "VIZIO E320i-B2"                                                              
[35] "Peg Perego John Deere Gator XUV"                                              "KidKraft Uptown Play Kitchen, Espresso"                                      
[37] "Lifetime 44\" Pro Court Height-Adjustable Portable Basketball Hoop"           "Canon PIXMA MG2920 printer"                                                  
[39] "Roadmaster Granite Peak 26\" Men's Mountain Bike, Black"                      "Zoomer Zuppies Interactive Puppy, Roxy"                                      
[41] "Butterball Digital Electric Extra-Large Fryer"                                "Mongoose Dolomite Mens 7-speed"                                              
[43] "LEGO Cuusoo Minecraft Building Set"                                           "Hoover SteamVac F5914900"                                                    
[45] "Razor RipRider 360 Ride-On, Blue"                                             "Cosco - Scenera Convertible Car Seat Renaissance"                            
[47] "Brother PE770"                                                                "RCA RTD317W"                                                                 
[49] "iPads, Tablets & eBook Readers"                                               "Televisions"                                                                 
[51] "iPads, Tablets & eBook Readers"                                               "Vacuum Cleaners"
```

My question is actually how to extract the values of this data frame column so it would be in the form of:

```
"Samsung UN48H6350 48\"" , "Sharp LC-60LE650U 60"  , "Roku Streaming Stick with remote"  ...
```

So I could take this list and pass it as parameter to dimnames(A) 
I tried:

```
rownames(products) <- products[,2] 
Error in rownames<-(*tmp*, value = c("Samsung UN48H6350 48\"", "Sharp LC-60LE650U 60", : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

> dput(products)
structure(list(id = 1:53, keywords = c("Samsung UN48H6350 48\"", 
"Sharp LC-60LE650U 60", "Roku Streaming Stick with remote", "Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4 16GB, Wi-Fi, 8.4in - White", 
"GoPro Here 3 silver", "Brunswick T Zone 16 lb. bowling ball", 
"SDBS-150 weight set", "Aventus by Creed Eau De Parfum Spray 4 oz Men", 
"Sunny SF-E906", "Sabrent 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub with Individual Power Switches and LEDs (HB-UMLS)", 
"Magnasonic MAG-MM176K", "NETGEAR Nighthawk AC1900  (R7000)", 
"FIDO U2F Security Key", "Foscam FI9821W V2 white", "Samsung UN22F5000", 
"D&K Seamless Full Length Leggings", "Taste of the Wild Dry Dog Food, Hi Prairie Canine Formula with Roasted Bison", 
"Tidy Cats 4 Count Breeze Litter Pad Refill (Pack of 10)", "PetSafe 6-Volt Lithium Battery (2 Batteries per Pack)", 
"Hakko CHP-170 Micro Clean Cutter", "Farm Innovators CC-2 Cord Connect Water-Tight Cord Lock - Green", 
"Komelon SL2925 Self Lock Speed Mark", "SanDisk 32GB Ultra Class 10 Micro SDHC", 
"Samsung (MB-MP32DA/AM)", "Panasonic ER-GN30-K", "Ubervita W700", 
"Baby Einstein Take Along Tunes", "Nosefrida The Snotsucker Nasal Aspirator", 
"Baby Einstein Bendy Ball", "Mommy's Helper Outlet Plugs 36 Pack", 
"Marcy Recumbent Exercise Bike: ME-709", "Doc McStuffins Get Better Talking Mobile Cart", 
"Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare Day Zero Edition (PS3)", "VIZIO E320i-B2", 
"Peg Perego John Deere Gator XUV", "KidKraft Uptown Play Kitchen, Espresso", 
"Lifetime 44\" Pro Court Height-Adjustable Portable Basketball Hoop", 
"Canon PIXMA MG2920 printer", "Roadmaster Granite Peak 26\" Men's Mountain Bike, Black", 
"Zoomer Zuppies Interactive Puppy, Roxy", "Butterball Digital Electric Extra-Large Fryer", 
"Mongoose Dolomite Mens 7-speed", "LEGO Cuusoo Minecraft Building Set", 
"Hoover SteamVac F5914900", "Razor RipRider 360 Ride-On, Blue", 
"Cosco - Scenera Convertible Car Seat Renaissance", "Brother PE770", 
"RCA RTD317W", "iPads, Tablets & eBook Readers", "Televisions", 
"iPads, Tablets & eBook Readers", "Vacuum Cleaners", "Bicycless"
), categories = c("11071", "11071", "168058", "171485", "625", 
"36105", "888", "26396", "15273", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"171485", "11071", "171485", "20614", "20614"), buyer_postal_code = c("90210", 
"90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", 
"90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", 
"90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", 
"90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", 
"90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", 
"90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", 
"90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", "90210", 
"90210", "90210", "90210"), min_price = c(200, 200, 0, 0, 100, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA), seller_item_id = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "111384136042", "111423002580", "191217437226", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "", NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("id", "keywords", 
"categories", "buyer_postal_code", "min_price", "seller_item_id"
), row.names = c(NA, -53L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: the error I get is "duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed" which is quit explicite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must resolve your issues with duplicate records first as a data frame is not allowed to have duplicate row names. for example

```
49 iPads, Tablets & eBook Readers     171485             90210         0               
51 iPads, Tablets & eBook Readers     171485             90210        NA           <NA>
```

Should not appear if you want this to be solved. Once you do that, your original attempt of `rownames(products) <- products[,2]` will work just fine.

If you must have the rownames as is, then a matrix *does* allow duplicate names:

```
> x <- as.matrix(products)
> rownames(x) <- x[, 2]
> head(x)                                                         
                                                      id   keywords                                                categories buyer_postal_code min_price seller_item_id
Samsung UN48H6350 48"                                 " 1" "Samsung UN48H6350 48\""                                "11071"    "90210"           "200"     NA            
Sharp LC-60LE650U 60                                  " 2" "Sharp LC-60LE650U 60"                                  "11071"    "90210"           "200"     NA            
Roku Streaming Stick with remote                      " 3" "Roku Streaming Stick with remote"                      "168058"   "90210"           "  0"     NA            
Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4 16GB, Wi-Fi, 8.4in - White " 4" "Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4 16GB, Wi-Fi, 8.4in - White" "171485"   "90210"           "  0"     NA            
GoPro Here 3 silver                                   " 5" "GoPro Here 3 silver"                                   "625"      "90210"           "100"     NA            
Brunswick T Zone 16 lb. bowling ball                  " 6" "Brunswick T Zone 16 lb. bowling ball"                  "36105"    "90210"           "  0"     NA
```

Comment: I did, I get an error: Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Samsung UN48H6350 48\"", "Sharp LC-60LE650U 60",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Comment: When you try a solution and it fails it is important to put that in your initial post as it gives clues to what might be unique about your problem. Can you add the output from `dput(products)` to your post?